# How to ask turtles to link with their link-neighbor's neighbor?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

For example:

Turtle 1 have link-neighbors [2, 3] and Turtle 2 have link-neighbors [1, 3, 4].

I want Turtle 1 to create link with one of Turtle 2's link-neighbors, but don't want Turtle 1 to create a link with itself (Turtle 1) or his existing link-neighbor (Turtle 2) - only Turtle 4 qualifies this condition.

And I want to write a "to go" function that asks all my N turtles to do this, like:

```
to go: 
 ask turtles [ make-friends ] 
end
 
to make-friends
 ;; turtle create a link with one of its link-neighbors' link-neighbor
 ;; who can not be its link-neighbor or itself
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following do?  turtle 1 would

```
let targets [link-neighbors] of turtle 2
let exclude link-neighbors
set targets other targets with [NOT member? self exclude]
create-link-to one-of targets
```

targets would first be the link-neighbors of turtle 2.  We then want to exclude turtle 1's own link neighbors, so we look for targets that are not in the excluded set, other than than turtle 1 itself.  Finally choose one to link to.  (We may need to check at each step to be sure that targets and exclude are not empty.)